# How to say reject a position after initially accepting it?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-change, manager

About a year back, I was hired by a big organization for a role that looked like my dream job on paper.

A couple of months ago, we were told that my current team would shut down and all the work was to be moved to a different country.

My manager offered me a different role instead, which while being a okayish  role, was not the "dream role" that I joined this company for. However, I need not give any interviews to join this new role.

But given that my team being shut down unexpectedly, and that I was not at all prepared to give job interviews, I had no option but to take this new role.

So I said yes to him while still looking for other opportunities.

I started prepping for interviews, and then applied to a different opening in my company that was much closer to what I was looking for.

Luckily I cleared their interviews and they are now willing to take me in.

How do I tell my manager that I am no longer interested in the role that he offered me?

He is sure to be very disappointed.

I am also wondering if I did the right thing by not being upfront about my aspirations.

Should I have told him that the second role he offered me was not that interesting? I am not sure how that would have gone. If I had told him that I wanted to shop around, and come work for him only if I could not get anything else, I don't think he could have taken it too kindly.

Is there anything I could have done to be more transparent and professional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refuse a job after accepting it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123370/refuse-a-job-after-accepting-it)

Comment: @JimG. I think taking a new position at the same employer because your existing job was moved/eliminated is different from seeking out new employment. Unlike the proposed duplicate, OP did not make or imply any promises* to be there

Comment: *OP, if you did in fact sign something promising to stay or have an employment contract that requires this, please add that to the question. I’m assuming you don’t because you don’t mention one.

Comment: I did not sign a contract because this was an internal movement, although I did tell my manager that I was going to join his team. My employer encourages internal movements because it is better than losing out an employee to the market.

Comment: Talk to your manager to ask for advice about this question. They may actually be relieved that you managed to save your job without needing them to find an assignment for you. If they **really** needs you in the assignment they found for you, they will tell you. At any rate thank them for looking out for you,

Answer (score 6):

> So I said yes to him while still looking for other opportunities.
>
> How do I tell my manager that I am no longer interested in the role
>   that he offered me?
>
> Is there anything I could have done to be more transparent and
>   professional?

I'm assuming that you accepted the new role without saying that you would still keep looking elsewhere. Doing so clearly would have been more transparent. But it wasn't necessary.

While your manager may be disappointed, I suspect he won't surprised. These things happen. When a company changes, roles may no longer fit well enough. You likely won't be the only one leaving.

Just tell him that something better came along. He'll understand. Give the proper notice and help those who you are leaving behind to the best of your ability. That's professionalism.

Answer (score 3):

> He is sure to be very disappointed.

I am not so sure about. The job that **you** really wanted is not there anymore. It is normal to think about a decission even though after "accepting it".

Remember what you said:

> which while being a okayish role, was not the "dream role" that I joined this company for.

You are the one that matters here! I think it is more than fair for you!